# Multiple Variables in R inputed as a vector

Tags: r, function

This might be really basic but i am unable to find a solution online.
Simplified, what i want to do is essentially use a vector as a collection of multiple input variables to a function.

Imagine the simple function

```
fun1<-function(a,b,c,d) {
a+b+c+d
}

inp<-c(1,2,3,4)
```

obviously this doesn't work but i want something equivalent to writing

```
fun1(inp)
```

or

```
mapply (fun1, inp)
```

to give me the result (10 in this case)

Is there a possible way to do this?

Thanks 
Sebastian

*EDIT*

I want to avoid having to manually input them... because i'm doing genetic programming and want to be able to change the number of variables of the function going in without needing to manually incorporate variables.

I thought I could generate a varying input vector to use somehow.

```
fitnessFunction1 <- function(f){ 
  for(k in 1:N) {
  meanerrors[k] <- rmse(mapply(f, input1[k,1], input1[k,2], input1[k,3], input1[k,4], input1[k,5]), output1[k]) 
  }}
```

don't want to write all the input1 in there but create a loop that creates the vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun1<-function(x) {
sum(x)
}

inp<-c(1,2,3,4)
fun1(inp)
```

or if you have to use them differently,

use

```
a<-x[1]
b<-x[2]
.......
```

inside function

or,
with your original function,

```
do.call(fun1, as.list(inp))
```

Comment: I want to avoid having to manually input them... because i'm doing genetic programming and want to be able to change the number of variables of the function going in without needing to manually incorporate variables. 

I thought I could generate a varying input vector to use somehow.

fitnessFunction1 <- function(f){ 
  for(k in 1:N) {
  meanerrors[k] <- rmse(mapply(f, input1[k,1], input1[k,2], input1[k,3], input1[k,4], input1[k,5]), output1[k]) 
  }}

don't want to write all the input1 in there but create a loop that creates the vector